# Sorting a file with perl using a Shell Script menu

Tags: bash, perl

I have a file with amount 10 random words. I am able to get my perl script to sort the file but i am not sure why as it sorts and overwrites the main file.
For example file.txt has: "a, c, d, b" i take read that file name in and then sort it into another filename sorted.txt "a, b, c, d" But i don't want to have my file.txt original file to change.

this is calling the perl sort function in my shell menu:

```
if [ "$choice" = 2 ]
    then
        perl perlsort.pl "$filename"
        cp $filename $outputfilename
fi
```

This is my perl code:

```
my $filename = shift @ARGV;
open(FH,$filename) or die "$!";
my @lines = <FH>;
close(FH);

$, = "\n";

open(my $output, ">", "$filename") or die "Unable to open $filename: $!\n";
print $output sort map { chomp; $_ } @lines;
close $output;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want Perl to overwrite your file, don't tell it to do so:

`open(my $output, ">", "$filename")` opens $filename for writing, i.e. overwrites it.

Maybe specify a different filename for the output, or use [File::Temp](http://p3rl.org/File::Temp).

BTW, it makes no sense to wrap $filename into double quotes in Perl, you can directly

```
open my $output, '>', $filename or die ...
```

Also, instead of chomping line by line, you can

```
chomp $lines;
```

Comment: As you can tell i am new to perl :)
How should i use the File::Temp?

Comment: I hate reading the manual pages, but you could always look up the documentation for File::Temp by typing such in the terminal: perldoc File::Temp

Answer (score 1):

You already write the sorted content to a file in your perl code. Try to replace "$filename" in `open(my $output, ">", "$filename")` to the new file name, so the script will write to the new file instead of rewriting the input file. With that don't forget to remove `cp $filename $outputfilename` from your bash script, otherwise it will replace the new file with the contents of the old (input) file. Or (if `$outputfilename` is different from the new file name in the perl script) it will create a new unsorted file with `$outputfilename` name and unsorted content, ending with 3 files: 2 with unsorted content and 1 - with sorted.